# How to sample 1:x where x is a vector of random integers with length greater than 1

Tags: r

The sample code

```
population <- 10000
vec <- sample(1:6, population, replace=T)    
output <- sample(1:vec, population, replace=T)
```

warning: numerical expression has 10000 elements: only the first used.

The sample is attempting to change the limits of the sample for each choice, so one iteration should randomly sample between 1:2, another could be between 1:6. The value of the maximum is defined in 'vec'

What is the correct way to structure this line such that it knows to create 'output' as a vector of length 10,000, with the proper references to the maximum values in 'vec'? Currently it is only using the first value of 'vec' for all 10000 samples in 'output'

Comment: In the first line you are sampling from a vector of 1:6 10,000 times then trying to use the 10,000 samples in a call to the `:` operator to define a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use `sapply` to loop over `vec`:

```
out <- sapply(vec,sample,size = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way: create a matrix where columns are samples using different numbers. Then build a vector that randomly takes a value from each row. I thought this might be faster, but both ways are very fast.

```
population <- 1e4
samp.mat <- sapply(1:6,sample.int,size=population,replace=TRUE)
indices <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(samp.mat)),sample.int(6,nrow(samp.mat),replace=TRUE))
out <- a[indices]
```